# Выполняет ли программа ограничения по времени и по памяти?

Tags: python

Вот условия задачи, будет ли задача подходить под один из форматов о эффективности по времени или памяти?

Дана последовательность
N целых положительных чисел. Рассматриваются
все пары элементов последовательности, разность которых чётна, и в этих
парах, по крайней мере, одно из чисел пары делится на 17. Порядок
элементов в паре неважен. Среди всех таких пар нужно найти и вывести пару
с максимальной суммой элементов. Если одинаковую максимальную сумму
имеет несколько пар, можно вывести любую из них. Если подходящих пар
в последовательности нет, нужно вывести два нуля.

Описание входных и выходных данных

В первой строке входных данных задаётся количество чисел
N (2 ≤
N ≤ 10 000). В каждой из последующих
N строк записано одно
натуральное число, не превышающее 10 000.

Пример входных данных:

```
5
34
12
51
52
51
```

Пример выходных данных для приведённого выше примера входных данных:

```
51 51
```

Пояснение. Из данных пяти чисел можно составить три различные пары,
удовлетворяющие условию: (34, 12), (34, 52), (51, 51). Наибольшая сумма
получается в паре (51, 51). Эта пара допустима, так как число 51 встречается
в исходной последовательности дважды.

Напишите эффективную по времени и памяти программу для решения этой
задачи.

Программа считается эффективной по времени, если при увеличении
количества исходных чисел
N в
k раз время работы программы увеличивается
не более чем в
k раз.

Программа считается эффективной по памяти, если память, необходимая для
хранения всех переменных программы, не превышает 1 Кбайт и не
увеличивается с ростом
N.

```
n=int(input())
n17h=0
n17n=0
neh=0
het=0
for i in range(0,n):
    g=int(input())
    if g%17==0 and g%2==0 and g>=n17h:
       n17h=g
    elif g%17==0 and g%2!=0 and g>n17n:
       n17n=g
    elif g%2==0 and g>het:
       het=g
    elif g%2!=0 and g>neh:
       neh=g
if het!=0 and n17h!=0 and (het+n17h>neh+het):
    print(het,n17h)
elif neh!=0 and n17n!=0 and (het+n17h<neh+het):
    print(neh,n17n)
else:
    print("00")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да. Не проверял программу на корректность работы, но эффективность по времени и по памяти такая, какая требуется в экзамене. По списку чисел осуществляется проход только один раз при вводе, память используется константного размера, вводимые числа не сохраняются в массив.